# Is there a Performance difference between a static Spring JPQL query vs a query that uses the Spring Specification API?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am working on a REST API that provides options to filter the data set based on certain criteria.

Generally, I have presumed that a statically defined JPQL will be faster than a query generated using the Spring Specification API (based on the principle that a static SQL query is faster than dynamic queries). Based on that, I have logic that actually uses the "static" query by default, but if there are filtering parameters, then I use the Specification API.

My question is, whether my assumption is incorrect here and whether I have added unnecessary complexity by doing this.

Comment: Measure and you will know. Why would one be slower then the other? The majority of the time is spend on the execution of the SQL (which should be the same) and parsing the results. One could even argue that a specification would be faster as that could eliminate the step of parsing the JPQL into a AST Tree and into SQL.

Comment: @M.Deinum "specification would be faster as that could eliminate the step of parsing the JPQL into a AST Tree and into SQL" - the reality is completely different: specifications (criteria api) get translated to JPQL first. BTW, specifications has some obvious disadvantage: since they do not implement `#equals` writing mocks is not possible and thus the only option to test the code is to perform integration tests.